# Find a solution for an equation

Tags: roots

Is there any way to find the solution for $x$ in this equation:

$$
x^2 = e^{2\mu} \left(e^{2x^2} - e^{x^2} \right)
$$

Where $\mu$ has a constant value.

I appreciate in advance.

Comment: Note that you can also solve for $x = e^{2\mu}(e^{2x} - e^x)$.

Comment: It is an equation which I get after a long calculations for engineering problem. I tried to do get the $log$ of left and right side of equation, but I think it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider
$$
e^{-2\mu}x^{2}=e^{2x^{2}}-e^{x^{2}}.
$$
Let $c=e^{-2\mu}$ and $w=x^{2}$. Then,
$$
cw=e^{2w}-e^{w}.
$$
Note that if $\mu\geq 0$, $c\leq 1$.

Now, try to show that for $c\leq 1$ and $0 \leq w < \infty$, the curves $cw$ and $e^{2w}-e^{w}$ intersect at only one point: $w=0$.

If, on the other hand, $c>1$, the curves also intersect at some point $w>0$. You will not be able to find a "nice" expression for this root.

Comment: So, in that case the only solution for positive value of $\mu$ would be zero. Am I right? or is there positive root for $w$?

Comment: You are right; I have clarified above.